# How to laod Raw HTML using jquery ajax call to ASP.net [Webmethod]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using follwoing code in , but In my webmethod I am returning plain HTML.
    Is contentType is right here ?

```
 function PopulateTimetable(pGroupId) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        url: "StudentTimetable.aspx/PopulateTimetable",
                        data: "{ 'pGroupId': '"+51+"'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "html",
                        timeout: 10000,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#divTimetable").removeClass("Progress");                        
                            $("#divTimetable").html("").append(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                                $("#divTimetable").removeClass("Progress");   
                                alert("An unexpected error has occurred during processing.");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used here  `$("#divTimetable").html("").append(data.d);` and it works fine now